# Are we suposed to consider $f(0)=1$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

If you plot the graph of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ on GeoGebra, you would realise that the function is shown to be continuous at $x=0$.

I do agree the $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, but $\frac{\sin0}{0}$ is a not a valid statement.

Thus, in general when we approach a question should we take $f(0)=\lim_\limits{x\to 0} f(x)$, or should we consider $f$ to be discontinuous at exactly one point (i.e. at $x=0$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is **not defined** at $0$, so it is neither continuous nor discontinuous at $x=0$.

However, you can also define a function

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}{x} & x \neq 0\\ 1& x=0\end{cases}$$

which is a *continuous function* on all real numbers, and is *equal* to $f$ on the domain of $f$.

Comment: And such an extension is unique.

Comment: So a function is not discontinuous at a point where it has a removable discontinuity?

Comment: @bof A function is not discontinuous at a point where it is not defined.

Comment: @bof Also, the function in question does not have a removable discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: @bof http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html by this definition, $f$ needs to be defined at a point in order to have a removeable discontinuity at that point.

Comment: Olmsted, *Real Variables*, p. 51: "The principal types of discontinuity are the following four: *(i) The limit of the function exists, but the function either is not defined at the point or has a value different from the limit there.* [.. .] Such a discontinuity is called a **removable discontinuity** because if the function is redefined to have the falue $f(a)\equiv\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ at $x=a,$ it becomes continuous there."

Comment: @bof Ok, by that definition, yes, it is true that a function **may not be** discontinuous at a point where it has a removable discontinuity. It is only discontinuous if it is actually defined there.

Answer (score 0):

You can not say that this function is discontinuous at $x = 0$. It is not defined at $0$.

However, you can extend the function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \sin x / x$ setting
$$
\tilde f(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x), & x \neq 0,\\
1,& x = 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Such $\tilde f$, defined on $\mathbb{R}$, is now continuous.